# Convert NCPDP script from XML to EDI

Tags: xml, edi

Is there a tool out there that can convert a Surescripts XML NewRx message to the NCPDP script 8.1 EDI format?

I did my messaging for Surescripts in XML, and now read the NIST test at http://xw2k.nist.gov/healthcare/docs/170.304.b_ExchangePrescriptionInformation_v1.0.pdf as requiring the EDI format instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two tools that I can think of that would be able to help you:

Softshare Delta / ECS - is a universal data translator that can map "any to any".  The mapper is quite slick, and inexpensive as well.

The other tool you might want to check out is [BridgeGate](http://www.bridgegateintl.com). They have some solid NCPDP integrations out there.

Comment: Thanks.  It is a little worrying when they don't give pricing :(  I found this site as well http://www.anshealth.com/ which has a GPL component buried inside the suite which does XML to SCRIPT transformations.

Comment: Delta / ECS should run approx $15K.  They were just acquired by Liaison, but I haven't heard of any pricing changes.  Their pricing was on their website as recently as last week, but with the acquisition, some of the marketing materials changed on the www.liaison.com site.  I can't speak to BridgeGate pricing...you'd have to call if interested.

Comment: No need now :)  NIST got their test suite wrong and the SCRIPT XML format is now acceptable.